# Chat edit does not show edit

Tags: bug, chat

I wrote a message in the chat, and then edited it. But when I submitted it, my change did not show up until I refreshed the page.

Comment: browser + version?

Comment: @Pee: I have seen this, too. FF, several versions over the last two years.

Comment: Chrome, latest user branch.

Comment: Are you getting this bug too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130422/se-chat-is-dropping-connections-occasionally-failing-to-update ? I see this bug after editing as well, and sometimes after posting

Answer (score 3):

I have this often, because I ninja-edit a lot and I'm pretty quick with the keyboard.

There's a delay sometimes.

If you edit too quickly there will be a race: the 'confirmation' of initial post received, will overwrite the later edit *locally only* and temporarily. Usually in `<1s` the edit confirmation is received and replaces the initial version locally too.

If a browser-refresh was necessary, you might want to look into the java console for errors (use Dragonfly/Firebug/IE developer toolbar etc.)
There might be a bug/browser incompatibility that blocked one of the chat events.